# Watchdog in Python to look for filesystem changes (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, watchdog, file-watcher

On my Mac, my code is working. Why doesn't it work on Windows 10?

```
from twilio.rest import Client 
import time 
import hashlib 
from datetime import date 
from watchdog.observers import Observer 
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class ModifiedEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        with open(pathname) as f:
            f = f.readlines()

            for line in f:
                code = hashlib.sha256(line.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                if pattern in line and code not in important:
                    important.append(code)
                    client.messages.create(to=TO, from_=FROM,
                                           body=MSG + str(date.today().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')))
                    break

            print(len(important))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = ModifiedEventHandler()

    my_observer = Observer()
    my_observer.schedule(event_handler, pathname, recursive=True)

    my_observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_observer.stop()
    my_observer.join()
```

When I execute the method on_modified the method is not executed:

```
 def on_modified(self, event):
        print(pathname)
```

log shows nothing at all and on my MAC it works.

Comment: Where does `FileSystemEventHandler` come from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre], and show any necessary `import`s etc. required to make the code work. We should be able to copy and paste your code and test it as is. Ideally, the code should *only* contain what is needed *to demonstrate the problem* - it does not need to be the entire code for the entire problem. If the problem is that `def on_modified(self, event):` doesn't get called at all, then we don't need anything beyond `pass`, or `print('on_modified was called')` for the body.

Comment: On the other hand, if `on_modified` *does* get called and just doesn't seem to have any *effect*, then the next question is to figure out *what actually is happening* when it gets called - and isolate the problem. See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: sorry here the imports: from twilio.rest import Client

import time
import hashlib
from datetime import date
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler